# Why we need to use multiple version of JQuery Libraries

Tags: jquery

I saw a lot of sites where people using multiple versions of Jquery library. My doubt is why we need to use multiple versions? Can't be use latest version only? Will that won't support all the previous versions functionality?

If we are using multiple versions, will our website loading will not be slow, as it is trying to load multiple versions.

Your comments will be very helpful to understand the things

Devesh

Comment: No : don't use multiple versions. Projects using multiple versions are messy. Always try to fix your different parts instead of try to deal with multiple versions.

Comment: jQuery 2.0 doesn't support IE8 so no, newer versions don't have the same functionality as old ones.

Comment: Only use the latest version.

Comment: Some people also tend to use more than one JavaScript framework in the same site. It's normally just the result of blinding copying scripts found in Google.

Comment: Some items are deprecated in the latest versions of jQuery so old functionality is essentially broken. This is why some people use Multiple Versions. It is `highly` advised that you only use the latest version and you fix your old functionality to work with the latest version.

Comment: if you are using some plugin which depend on jquery old version then sometime developer using multiple version.But it is wrong practice.

Comment: Please read http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web site using multiple versions of jQuery is

- slower as it loads and run more code
- more complex as you have to add hooks to ensure each library uses the right jQuery
- messy, as the developers need to master the different versions

When a library uses jQuery, this library *must* be up to date. Fix your libraries for the version of jQuery you'll use for your site. Never try to jungle with multiple versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use multiple versions of jQuery. If you want functions from older versions of jQuery, then you should include [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) too.

Answer (score 1):

Is not good way to load multiple versions of JQuery. It is very heavy library and can slow down the site.

Sometimes people are not skilled in framewrok and doing mistake.
In old Jquery libs there are some methods who don't exist in new versions. For example **live()** method. Peole don't waste time to rewrite code.